# The name "getView" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments

I am building an Android application that uses fragments to display different views. The first tab contains the code below. Unfortunately, I get this error:

> The name 'getView' does not exist in the current context

I also tried placing the getView() in onActivityCreated, rather than onViewCreated, but I received the same error. Why is getView not being recognized?

```
namespace BottomToolbar
{
    public class FirstFragment : Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public static FirstFragment NewInstance()
        {
            var fragment = new FirstFragment { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return fragment;
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.FirstFragment, container, false);
            return view;
        }

        public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Button button = (Button)getView().findViewById(Resource.Id.getWeatherButton);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `getView()` with `view` it's not Java code it's C#

Comment: You are pasting Java code inside the C# code. Xamarin is nealy translated 1:1 to native Android Java code, but there are some changes, per example the function `getView` is replaced by the property `View` (Java does not have properties like C#), `findViewById` is `FindViewById<T>` and so on.

Comment: I changed the code per your directions Yupi and Gusman and the error went away. I will write up an answer to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Button button = (Button)getView().findViewById(Resource.Id.getWeatherButton);
```

to

```
Button button = View.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.getWeatherButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button button = (Button)view.getView().findViewById(Resource.Id.getWeatherButton); }
```